# Improve performance migration

Tags: 9, migrations

I have a custom migration like this

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_import\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\migrate_source_csv\Plugin\migrate\source\CSV;

/**
 * Extend CSV source.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "my_source_csv",
 *   source_module = "my_import"
 * )
 */
class MySourceCSV extends CSV {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    parent::prepareRow($row);
    // Prepare data for $row; 

  }
}
```

In the prepare data for $row step. I have some business logic and it take along time although this logic return an array
same with every rows. Images this step take about 2 seconds, and import very larger rows...

So I want to create a global variable when starting import. and using this variable each rows, and when finish import clear this variable.

How can I implement this idea? With me global variable is better than process data and store in DB (example drupal state, still query each rows).

Comment: Does an object property not work?

Comment: @cilefen sorry what do you mean? My problem is about fllow of migration. each rows of csv file will call method prepareRow, and run my login business every rows. while my business logic return an array same with every rows.

Comment: In object-oriented programming, object properties can store values. This is what I mean. It's ordinary to check `if empty($this->foo) { //do expensive calculation}; $this->foo = $result_of_calculation;`.